Interrupted initial update
Yesterday I installed Xubuntu 24.04.  Today I was greeted by Software Updater informing me that there have been changes since the release back in April. I viewed the files that were to be downloaded.  I started to run the Updater, but, because of confusion, I cancelled before all files were downloaded.  Then i opened Software Updater again, but the list of files it presented me with did not include the system files in the original notification.  My question is: Have I done something that destroyed my chances of getting certain vital and necessary updates?

Your system should be fine...if you are patient.
If you ignore the package manager and keep using your system normally, an Ubuntu system will re-check it's own status again in a few hours. It typically checks for deb updates twice each day. Then you will get the update dialog again, and that dialog should be accurate.
If you're not patient, and want to force the re-check immediately, then open a terminal and run sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade. Read all output carefully, do not proceed if there is an error message.

Open a terminal, and run the two commands one-by-one to install all available updates.
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

